# How to implement a recursive function to save the elements of the N-th Cartesian Power of (0,1,...,N) in C++?

Tags: c++, recursion, cartesian-product

If the question is not clear, I want to have for example if N=4 a result like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 . . . .
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 . . . .
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 . . . .
0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 . . . .
```

This is my function:

```
int Combinazioni(int i, int N, vector<vector<int>> & combs){ 
if(i<N) {
    for (int k=0; k<=N; k++){
            combs[i].push_back(k);
            return(Combinazioni(i+1,N, combs));
    }
    for(int j=0; j<N-1;j++){
        while(combs[j].size()<combs[N-1].size()){
            combs[j].push_back(combs[j].back());
        }
    }
} 
return 1;
```

}

where combs is a vector of vectors that I have initialized with N rows, and then I'll transpose it for better accessibility...

When I compile it gives me this:
*warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]*
and when I execute it prints

```
0
0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

There must definitely be some bug in the logic of my recursion but I'm not very good at visualizing it so if there's an easy and elegant way to do this or to solve the bug I'd be grateful, thank you.

P.S. I think it doesn't really need to be super-efficient, and in fact if there's a better alternative to recursion, or some effective library, it would be equally fine for my purpose

Comment: *"If the question is not clear,"* -- since this is the first sentence of your question, I would go with "not clear by virtue of not existing".

Comment: Replace `else return 1` with `return 1`.

Comment: Your "loop" unconditionally returns at first iteration...

Comment: Warning is a false positive here. Your `if` branch only returns if loop is taken, so if `0/*k*/ <= N`, you have indeed `0 <= i && i < N`, but the checker don't go that far.

Comment: `1*Combinations(i+1,N, combs)` is simply `Combinations(i+1,N, combs)`.

Comment: From description, you probably want [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) and not [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you for the reply, indeed it is Cartesian product and that's why I hadn't find satisfying help in previous discussions... Nevertheless even looking for Cart. Prod. in C++ with recursion didn't find solutions not extremely complex/general for my purpose... I edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Hard coded solution would look like:

```cpp
std::vector<int> values{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
for (int a1 : values) {
  for (int a2 : values) {
    for (int a3 : values) {
      for (int a4 : values) {
        for (int a5 : values) {
            do_job({a1, a2, a3, a4, a5});
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

More generic solution might be:

```
bool increase(std::size_t max_size, std::vector<std::size_t>& it)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0, size = it.size(); i != size; ++i) {
        const std::size_t index = size - 1 - i;
        ++it[index];
        if (it[index] > max_size) {
            it[index] = 0;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void iterate(std::size_t max_size, std::size_t len)
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> it(len, 0);

    do {
        do_job(it);
    } while (increase(max_size, it));
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6dbff76fd08c5209)